# gradle does not add native libraries from fresco

Tags: android, gradle

i want to add fresco to my project so according to official site i put

> compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0+'

into my gradle file. but after running the apk it fails on UnsatisfiedLinkError. i looked into my .apk and there is no /lib folder that should contain its .so files. i found out on the internet that gradle doesn't support .so files but i have seen projects that got it actually working, so there must be a way.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why you are referring to .so files? Fresco doesn't contain .so files.

Comment: yes it does. when you download zip file from this page
http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html#_
you can see there are .so files in imagepipeline/libs folder

Comment: and they are required for some features to work (gifs in my case)

Comment: please post full error message.

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/<blablapackage>apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/<blablapackage>/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmemchunk.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
    at com.facebook.common.soloader.SoLoaderShim$DefaultHandler.loadLibrary(SoLoaderShim.java:34)
    at com.facebook.common.soloader.SoLoaderShim.loadLibrary(SoLoaderShim.java:56)
and so on

Comment: i've searched all over internet and official fresco answers for this are "your libmemchunk.so is in wrong directory. put it in armeabi-v7" or something like that. but my problem is that there is no lib folder with no armeabi folder and no libmemchunk.so files aswell